# React - Is order guaranteed when sequentally calling Setter methods

Tags: reactjs

I have possible sequential setter calls when handling a Fetch result, e.g.

```
fetch("...")
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                //...
                setFormSubType("");
                //...
                if (condition) { 
                   setFormSubType(obj.someProperty);
                }
```

In React, the setter calls are always asynchronous. But can I be guaranteed that the order will be followed: in the case condition is TRUE, the 2nd setter will always complete **after** the 1st setter call, and the final result will be a non-empty string?

Comment: What do you mean by "*The setter calls are asynchronous*"? What are they doing?

Comment: I mean in React, the setters are always asynchronous - they won't necessarily complete when you go to the next line of your code.

Comment: Complete with what? Are you talking about state setters?

Comment: No you can't, you have to use `useEffect`